# Multiple cases in switch statement (that continues on after case statements)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to get a JavaScript function to perform a switch statement that doesn't behave like a normal switch statement (i.e. `switch`, `case`, `break`) however, I am not sure how to go about it. Basically I am wanting a switch statement to continue on assessing against the cases without breaking until it gets to the end. I.e.

```
function AddData(cell,totalCell) {
  var total = 0;
  switch (cell) {
    case "AUT":
      total = totalCell;
    case "FRA":
      total = total + totalCell;
    case "DEU":
      total = total + totalCell;
    case "GRC":
      total = total + totalCell;
    case "SVK":
      total = total + totalCell;
    break;
  }
  return total;
}
```

FYI, this is being used with Google Spreadsheets.

Any assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I expect to call the AddData function like this: `AddData(A:A,B:B)` on a spreadsheet that would look something like this:

```
AUT  3.4
FRA  3.3
ITA  4.7
SWE  3.0
FRA  1.1
FRA  3.7
LVA  5.2
```

In the case above I would expect the output to be `11.5`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean a switch statement [fallthrough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough)?

Comment: That's not the way `switch` fallthrough works. If `cell` is "AUT", it will perform all of your cases until the `break`. Since `cell` can only be one value at a time, I would put in a break after each case.

Comment: Please provide function input. What are the potential values of `input`?

Comment: Please provide not only sample input, but the expected output, so we can understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey - just made an edit to the original question with more info about the spreadsheet and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things needed tweaking.

1. When you use ranges as parameters, they are presented to your custom function as two-dimensional arrays. In this case, you intended to pass a column, so the array will be an array of rows, where each row is an array with one element. To access each cell in the column, you need to iterate through the rows, like this:

   ```
   for (var i in cell) { do_something_with( cell[i][0] ) }
   ```

   It would be more efficient (and some would say, correct) to loop using `for (var i=0; i < cell.length; i++)`.
2. Case fall-through - since you appear to want to do the same thing for every country code, you only need ONE code block. (As others pointed out, without a `break` after every code block, your original code would have fallen through and repeated every operation following the first match.)
3. I think that the original code block for `case "AUT"` was in error, and that you do, in fact, want to sum up for all country codes.

#### code

```
function AddData(cell,totalCell) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i in cell) {
    switch (cell[i][0]) {
      case "AUT":
      case "FRA":
      case "DEU":
      case "GRC":
      case "SVK":
        total = total + totalCell[i][0];
        break;
    }
  }
  return total;
}
```

#### Problems

This function is not robust, and you really should rethink what you're trying to do.

- The two parameters have an implicit relationship, but there is no explicit connection between them. This presents a risk that they will not actually match in length or meaning. This could be improved by taking a multi-column range as input instead, guaranteeing that the two columns match.
- What do you want to do with country values outside of the list you have in your case statement? Right now, everything else is quietly ignored, but what if another country value was input... would you want it? (Maybe you need to treat blanks differently than new values? Maybe you want to `throw` if an unknown country is input?)

Comment: Would it be possible to write the switch using `foreach()`?